can not find path for sqlite db in Maui app
i try to create local sqlite db in maui app .
private const string DbName = "SweetsShopDb.db3";
private static string DbPath => Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(
    

                                Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), DbName);

        public async Task Init()
        {
            Database = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(DbPath,
                SQLiteOpenFlags.Create | SQLiteOpenFlags.ReadWrite | SQLiteOpenFlags.SharedCache);
            await Database.CreateTableAsync<User>();
        }

after initializing the class
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<SweetsShopDb>();


protected override async void OnAppearing()     {       base.OnAppearing();

        await _sweetsShopDb.Init();     }

it gives me path that cannot accessed
"/data/user/0/com.amr.sweetsshop/files/SweetsShopDb.db3 "so i cannot find this path .
i also checked for this path "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Packages\com.amr.sweetsshop_9zz4h110yvjzm\LocalState"
but folder is empty
how get this path...

gives me path that cannot accessed Accessed by who?

By me , I want to reach the sqliteDb file .I cannot reach the path that appears from filesystem.Appdata or special folder.localAppData

By you? You cannot reach paths. Only apps can. So the question is now: how did you try? Which software did you use?

Iam running maui android app on emulator . I was trying to reach the sqlite db file on localAppData on my PC. I thought itis possible

The same app that created the db? If so then show the code that fails.

You need to use adb to copy the file from the Android filesystem to your desktop
